# Always Standard never Leap Year

Tags: javascript

Whenever I input a year whether it is standard or not, the code below which needs to stay the same as that was my instructions when I started trying to debug it. It shows the alert standard year.

```js
function checkLeapYear() {
  var year = document.yearForm.year.Value;
  if (year % 4 != 0) { //was missing {
    window.alert("The year you entered is a standard year.");
  }
  //was missing { below
  else if (year / 400 == 0) {
    window.alert("The year you entered is a leap year.");
    window.alert("The year you entered is a standard year.");
  } //was missing }
  else { //was missing {
    window.alert("The year you entered is a leap year.");
  } //was missing }
}
```

```html
<form name="yearForm" action="">
  <p>Year:
    <input type="text" name="year" />
    <br />
    <input type="button" value="Check for Leap Year" onclick="checkLeapYear();" />
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: You have two `window.alert()` calls one after another in the `else if  (year / 400 == 0)` block. You should only have one. Also you are missing the check for years divisible by 100 (those years are NOT leap years). Perhaps that check is supposed to be between the adjacent `window.alert()` calls.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean by that

Comment: "year / 400 == 0" - which year is that?

Comment: I believe he meant `year % 400`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var year = document.yearForm.year.Value;
```

should be

```
var year = document.yearForm.year.value;
```

Your `year` is `undefined`. The result of `undefined % 4` is `NaN`. `NaN != 0` is true.

Comment: my year is defined base off what the user puts

Comment: @Diana - DOM element corresponding to `input` tag does not have property "Value", it has property "value" - javascript is a case-sensitive language. When you read a non-existing property of an object, you get back `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

So now you have your answer, here is how to test for real:

```js
function isLeap(year) {
  var d = new Date(year,1,29,12,0,0,0);
  return d.getDate()===29;  
}

alert("1900:"+isLeap(1900)+"\n2000:"+isLeap(2000)+"\n2001"+isLeap(2001)+"\n2004"+isLeap(2004))
```